# How do I add user input to an Array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    int n;
    String a;     
    System.out.println("Enter the Class:");
    a = user_input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of Students:");
    n = user_input.nextInt();
    for (i= 1; i <= n; i++) {
        String g = a + i;
        System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

This is my program. It gets user input for the Class and prints the Roll Number for the students.

For example: If the class is **10A** and the number of students is **10**, it prints a series like **10A1 , 10A2, 10A3 ... 10A10**

How do I get the program to store these as elements in an array?

For example:

```
array[0] = 10A1;
array[1] = 10A2;
array[2] = 10A3;
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    int n;
    String a;
    System.out.println("Enter the Class:");
    a = user_input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of Students:");
    n = user_input.nextInt();
    String []strings = new String[n]; // Creating an are of string with the given number
    for(i= 0; i < n ;){
        strings[i] = a + ++i; // Storing strings on to the array !
        System.out.println(strings[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit each index in your current for loop:

```
String[] arr;
for(i=0; i < n ; i++){
  int j = i+1;

  String g = a + j;
  System.out.println(g);

  arr[i] = g;
}
```

So all your printed `g`'s will be part of the array `arr`.

Comment: Please execute your code ! it will give weird output ! because you are incrementing i twice !

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a `String` array of the appropriate size.

Second, in your `for` loop, assign the strings you are currently printing, to positions in the array.

```
String[] things = new String[n];
for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
    String g = a + i;
    System.out.println(g);
    things[i-1] = g;
}
```

The strings are now in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is modified, for storing values in array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
         Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int i;
         int n;
         String a;     

         System.out.println("Enter the Class:");
         a = user_input.next();
         System.out.println("Enter the number of Students:");
         n = user_input.nextInt();

         String[] arr = new String[n];  // create string array of size n.

         for(i= 1; i <= n ; i++){
            String g = a + i;
            System.out.println(g);
            arr[i-1]=g;  // assign your g veriable vale to array index
        }

         for(String s : arr){
             System.out.println(s);   // print your array
         }

    }
```